# MySQL SUM, join and union 4 tables

Tags: mysql, join, sum, union

I have 4 tables with similar column name:

```html
Table 1 : simp_wajib
id    anggota    nilai
1     nama1      100
2     nama2      100
3     nama1      100

Table 2 : simp_pokok
id    anggota    nilai
1     nama2      100
2     nama3      100
3     nama1      100

Table 3 : simp_sukarela
id    anggota    nilai
1     nama2      100
2     nama2      100
3     nama1      100

Table 4 : simp_berjangka
id    anggota    nilai
1     nama3      100
2     nama2      100
3     nama3      100
```

I try to join the four tables with following query but it give me incorrect sum value

```html
SELECT nama.anggota, sum(simp_wajib.nilai) as wajib, sum(simp_pokok.nilai) as pokok,sum(simp_sukarela.nilai) as sukarela,sum(simp_berjangka.nilai) as berjangka
FROM
(SELECT anggota from simp_pokok
 UNION
 SELECT anggota FROM simp_wajib) nama
 LEFT JOIN simp_pokok ON simp_pokok.anggota=nama.anggota
 LEFT JOIN simp_wajib ON simp_wajib.anggota=nama.anggota
 LEFT JOIN simp_sukarela ON simp_sukarela.anggota=nama.anggota
 LEFT JOIN simp_berjangka ON simp_berjangka.anggota=nama.anggota
 group by nama.anggota
```

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you join the tables, you will end up with more lines than you expect, because the join will cross the values between the tables.
What you probably need, is a union between all your tables, to summarize the common values, grouped by the common column first, and then from a custom field you will add to keep track of the origin table.

Finally, you will transpose the results with a CASE statement.

```
select anggota, 
sum(CASE WHEN origin = 'simp_pokok' THEN nilai END) `simp_pokok`,
sum(CASE WHEN origin = 'simp_wajib' THEN nilai END) `simp_wajib`,
sum(CASE WHEN origin = 'simp_sukarela' THEN nilai END) `simp_sukarela`,
sum(CASE WHEN origin = 'simp_berjangka' THEN nilai END) `simp_berjangka`
from (
    SELECT nama.anggota, sum(nilai) as nilai, origin
    FROM
    (SELECT anggota, nilai, 'simp_pokok' as origin from simp_pokok
     UNION ALL
     SELECT anggota, nilai, 'simp_wajib' as origin FROM simp_wajib
     UNION ALL
     SELECT anggota, nilai, 'simp_sukarela' as origin FROM simp_sukarela
     UNION ALL
     SELECT anggota, nilai, 'simp_berjangka' as origin FROM simp_berjangka
    ) nama
    group by nama.anggota, nama.origin) united
group by anggota
```

if you don't like the "null" values, you can wrap the sum() with a coalesce function, like

```
coalesce(sum(CASE ...), 0) as `simp_pokok`
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this works perfectly as expected. I add coalesce as per your suggest to avoid NULL

Answer (score 0):

With your query, the result is as follow

```html
anggota nilai  origin
1  200  simp_berjangka
1  200  simp_pokok
1  100  simp_sukarela
1  400  simp_wajib
2  300  simp_sukarela
2  500  simp_wajib
3  100  simp_pokok
3  200  simp_sukarela
4  200  simp_berjangka
```

My expected output is each sum value which is grouped by anggota become a column

```html
anggota sum(simp_pokok) sum(simp_wajib) sum(simp_berjangka) sum(simp_sukarela)
1  200  400  200  200
2  0  500  0  300
3  100  0  0  200      
4  0  0  200  0
```

Comment: check my edited answer and see if it solves your problem